# SnowflakeSQL get me last text after specific char

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to retrieve last part of string after underscore.. but every record has different number of underscore and I'm not sure how to write it correctly.

Example:

aaa_bb_cccc_dddd_ee  - only ee
aaa_bb_cccc_dddd     - only dddd
sss_aas_ww_ww_ww_bb  - only bb

As you can see there is different number of underscore and I need only last part after last underscore.

I have been playing with regex and split_part but since I don't now how to point to the last _ then it's not working correctly.

My Idea is to start reading string from the right a then you just pick the first one but couldn't find a way how to do it.

It's probably basic thing but I'm struggling with it so please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '_([^_]+)$', 1, 1, 'e', 1) AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `split_part` change the direction of split using negative integers

```
select split_part(col,'_',-1)
from your_table;
```

You could also just `regexp_replace` everything up until and including the last underscore

```
select regexp_replace(col,'.*_','')
from your_table;
```